# Maven build pauses when spring-boot application required stdin from user

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I have a simple springboot project created for standalone application. Main method implements the `run` method of `ApplicationRunner` interface

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication implements ApplicationRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {

        final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        final String inputFilePath = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println(inputFilePath);
    }
}
```

The application can be executed without an issue. But when the application is built through maven, the build pauses in the middle and asking for the user input to be entered. It's because I have used the scanner to get the user input for the execution

No changes were done to the pom file (It is the default spring-boot pom)

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Simple java maven project does not have this issue. It builds successfully. This only comes with this spring-boot project. What am I doing wrong here? Do I need to add some kind of a parameter to the `spring-boot-maven-plugin`

And I have several unit tests written as well.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ValidationTest {

    @Autowired
    private ValidationService validationService;

    @Test
    public void test_1() {
        final String number = "8801673191614";
        boolean result = validationService.isValidMSISDN(number);

        Assert.assertTrue(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong, you probably have a test with `@SpringBootTest` which bootstraps the full application and thus will ask for input.

Comment: Yes, I have. I have updated the question as well. And I am auto-wiring the actual service here to test. When the annotations @SpringBootTest are removed, the autowired dependency will become null always. What is the ideal solution for this

Comment: Don't use `@SpringBootTest` for this. Just create the instance of the service yourself in the test case and make it a proper unit test instead of an integration test.

Answer (score 0):

Build your project with `-Dmaven.test.skip=true` arguments. The problem is that when you run the tests, all the Spring Context runs.